# timestamp in laravel won't update

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, date, timestamp

I have a column in my table Blis called "deadline". The type is timestamp. I am using MySQL db.

When I save a date in the format "yy-mm-dd h:i:s" it saves fine, but whenever I try to update it to some other date, it just won't save.

Let's say i have 2019-02-17 00:00:00 in one row and want to update to 2019-05-05 09:30:00, the changes won't take even though the rest of the row does get updated.

Migration:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('blis', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->timestamp('deadline')->default(null)->nullable();
    });
}
```

Controller:

```
public function update(Bli $bli)
    {

        $attributes = request()->validate(
            [
            'title' => ['required', 'min:3'],
            'description' => ['nullable'],
            'status_id' => ['required'],
            'deadline' => ['date_format:Y-m-d H:i:s']
            ]
        );

        $bli->update(request(['title', 'description', 'status_id', 'deadline']));



        return redirect("/bli/$bli->id");
    }
```

Html:

```
<div class="form-group ">
      <label for="deadline">Deadline:</label>
      <input class="form-control" type="text" id="datepicker" name="deadline" placeholder="Date" value="{{$bli->deadline}}">
</div>
```

And I am using jquery UI's datepicker for the input field:

```
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
    dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd 00:00:00"
});
```

Even when I remove validation, the value of "deadline" still won't update.

Is timestamp the correct type to use in this situation ? If so, why won't it update when the rest of the row does ? If not, which is the correct date type to use in this case ?

Comment: the date_format doesn't amend the format of the request data, it just checks that it is the same format - just checking whether you knew that or not

Comment: Yes, already knew. I wanted to validate the date in this format before it is saved in the db. @CodeBoyCode

Comment: You absolutely sure that the field on the form is called `deadline`

Comment: Yep, included the html in the question. @RiggsFolly

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I presume you are using Laravel. In which case, make sure `deadline` is within the `fillable` array.

```php
protected $fillable = [
    ...
    'deadline',
    ...
]
```

Otherwise Laravel will not store the value.